# Does autolayouts supports RTL views using constraints?

Tags: ios, view, localization, autolayout, right-to-left

I have localized my application in arabic. While in arabic culture, I need to mirror my views using constraints like trailing and leading. what are the best practices to have a flipped view? 

It may be interesting to note that when set to Arabic, its culture is set as @"ar-AE". I guess flipping the view doesn't work with the @"ar-AE" locale, although I'm unsure whether that's a bug, or if some arabic countries write LTR, thus making sense not to systematically flip the view.

Long story short what constraint settings are required to actually convert view into "Arabic" and properly flip a view?

Comment: you can add conditional constraints

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using Leading and Trailing constraints is in theory all you should have to do.

The language variant should be independent of the appended region, and fall back to the generic language for layout information. If you are seeing LTR views in ar but not ar-AE, you should file a bug at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com).